# SQL Server Backup Command Error

Tags: sql, database, visual-studio-2010, t-sql, backup

I am trying to create a backup of my SQL Server Database in Visual Studio 2010.

I am using the following command to back up the database:

> BACKUP DATABASE Db TO DISK = 'c:\server.bak'

This is connection string that I am using.

```
<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Db.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

However, when I run the command, I get the following error message.

Database 'Db' does not exist.

Here is a screenshot that describes my error:

http://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/aerfanfa/sqlerror.jpg

Does anyone have a solution for my problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is: your database `db.mdf` is **not** attached to the SQL Server Express instance - therefore, you cannot back it up.

This whole `AttachDbFileName=.....` story is a bit tricky - and quite a mess, if you ask me.

I would recommend to just forget about using that `AttachDbFileName=...` stuff, and instead:

- just attach the `db.mdf` file to your local SQL Server Express instance (using SQL Server Management Studio Express)
- talk to the attached database using it's **logical database name** instead of messing around with a `.mdf` file

Once you've done that - **then** you can use commands like `BACKUP DATABASE ...` and everything else!

Your connection string would be much simpler, too!

```
<add name="ConnectionString" 
     connectionString="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=YourDatabaseName;Integrated Security=True;"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try right clicking the database in Manament studio, selecting tasks, then "Backup".  After setting the parameters, you can select "Script" which will give you a proper backup script.

A backup script looks something like:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [Db] TO  DISK = 
N'C:\Server.bak'
 WITH NOFORMAT, INIT,  NAME = N'Db Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, 
STATS = 10
GO
```